# Can you help diagnose why this laptop running Ubuntu has crashed and seemingly died

Tags: laptop

My laptop had Window Vista on previously (sorry). Something went wrong, I can't remember, and I tried to reinstall but couldn't, installed a replacement second hand HD, and installed Ubuntu instead. It worked ok for a little while, before crashing.  I ended up reloading Ubuntu three times.  It works for a while after (say 3-5 hrs of domestic web browsing), and then crashes.

When I turn it on now, it comes up with some options to restart in safe mode, run tests and so on. I can't get it to start normally. I'm not going to re-install again.

Below are screen shots of what happens when I follow some of these test options.  These screen shots mean nothing to me.  Any ideas? Surely I can fix this....

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The screenshot says "unrecovered read error", which usually suggests that the hard drive is dying. Get a new hard drive.

However, if this is the second hard drive dying in your laptop in a short period of time it may suggest that the problem is somewhere else - maybe in the SATA controller, faulty RAM, laptop overheating etc.

At any rate, Ubuntu is not at fault :)

Comment: I believe on the Ubuntu installation CD, in the first bootmenu, probably a submenu of this, you should find a utility named memtest86 which will check if your RAM is faulty somewhere. But like Sergey I'd rather go for the HDD or SATA-controller, the latter one is unfortunately not interchangable in a Laptop.